# Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'Employee' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF

Tags: java, sql-server

I created a project and it worked fine with MySQL.
After making SQL Server instead of MySQL, I encounter a problem: Read, Update and Delete work fine, however I can't create a new Employee.
Bellow are:
**SpringMain.java**

```html
public class SpringMain
{
 public static void main(String[] args)
 {
  ClassPathXmlApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring.xml");
  EmployeeDAO employeeDAO = ctx.getBean("employeeDAOJDBCTemplate", EmployeeDAO.class);
  Employee emp = new Employee();
  emp.setName("Saria");
  emp.setRole("CEO");
  employeeDAO.save(emp);
 }
}
```

**spring.xml**

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

 <bean id="employeeDAO" class="com.journaldev.spring.jdbc.dao.EmployeeDAOImpl">
  <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
 </bean>
 
 <bean id="employeeDAOJDBCTemplate" class="com.journaldev.spring.jdbc.dao.EmployeeDAOJDBCTemplateImpl">
  <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
 </bean>
 
 <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
  <property name="driverClassName" value="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver" />
  <property name="url" value="jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;database=bbb"/>
  <property name="username" value="lm" />
  <property name="password" value="pp" />
 </bean>

</beans>
```

**Employee.java**

```html
@Entity
@Table(name="Employee")
public class Employee 
{
 @Id      
 @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
 @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
 private int id;
 
 @Column(name = "name")
 private String name;
 
 @Column(name = "role")
 private String role;
 
 public Employee() {}
 public Employee(int id, String name, String role)
 {
  this.id = id;
  this.name = name;
  this.role = role;
 }
}
```

**EmployeeDAOJDBCTemplateImpl**

```html
public class EmployeeDAOJDBCTemplateImpl implements EmployeeDAO 
{
 private DataSource dataSource;

 public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) 
 {
  this.dataSource = dataSource;
 }
 
 @Override
 public void save(Employee employee)
 {
  String query = "insert into Employee (id, name, role) values (?,?,?)";
  JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
  Object[] args = new Object[] {employee.getId(), employee.getName(), employee.getRole()};
  int out = jdbcTemplate.update(query, args);
  if(out !=0)
  {
   System.out.println("Employee saved with id="+employee.getId());
  }
  else System.out.println("Employee save failed with id="+employee.getId());
 }
}
```

**EmployeeDao.java**

```html
public interface EmployeeDAO
{
 public void save(Employee employee);
}
```

**The Query which I generated on SQL Server is:**

```css
CREATE TABLE [bbb].[dbo].[Employee]
(
 id int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
 name varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 role varchar(255) NOT NULL
)
```

The Exception that appears after running the file SpringMain.java is

```js
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: PreparedStatementCallback; SQL [insert into Employee (id, name, role) values (?,?,?)]; Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'Employee' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.; nested exception is com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'Employee' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.
 at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.doTranslate(SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.java:243)
 at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:73)
 at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:658)
 at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:907)
 at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:968)
 at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:978)
 at com.journaldev.spring.jdbc.dao.EmployeeDAOJDBCTemplateImpl.save(EmployeeDAOJDBCTemplateImpl.java:32)
 at com.journaldev.spring.jdbc.main.SpringMain.main(SpringMain.java:31)
Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'Employee' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.
 at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:197)
```

After googling, I found that I have to put

```html
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[IdentityInsert] ON
```

However, this can't resolve the exception.
Could you please tell me what's missing ?. Thanks in advance.

Comment: How are you inserting those values?

Comment: I'm using those two classes:

Comment: Why do you want to insert the value of `id` by yourself? If you have to insert manually then remove the IDENTITY_SPECIFICATION. It doesn't make sense at all

Comment: if you want to explicitly insert a value for `id`, then why did you make that column an `IDENTITY`?

Comment: Really, please excuse me Mr. JONJON and Lamak for this foolishness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IDENTITY(1,1) means insert the value of that column automatically starting from `seed` value i.e 1 (before comma) and increment the value by `increment` i.e. 1 (after comma) whenever a new row is inserted.

If you want the `id` to be autogenerated then you need to do some changes like

```
public Employee(String name, String role){    
    this.name = name;
    this.role = role;
}
```